# I can't see my app on TestFlight

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm an admin for my team on App Store Connect, and we have several users testing our app on TestFlight. I'm added as an Internal Tester for the app, but when I open TestFlight I don't see the app (I see other apps I'm a tester for, but not this one). I went to the Internal Testers list on App Store Connect and removed and re-added myself, and immediately got an email saying "build X is read to test on iOS. To test this app, open `TestFlight`", which I clicked, it took me to TestFlight, and said "this build is no longer available. This build is the one I just pushed out and is available to all other testers.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. I have 3 apps that I test as an internal user. 2 of them show but 1 does not. I've removed and re-added myself several times but still can't get the third app to show in the apps list in Test Flight